# Have child of parent with position absolute or fixed stretch to full height of viewport

Tags: jquery, css, position, css-position, absolute

I have this thing that's been bugging me.

It's a ScrollToFixed element with a slideToggle element in it. The slideToggle element should expand to 100% of the viewport height when revealed. What complicates this is that the parent element either have `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, depending on if the browser have been scrolled or not. As the slide element should cover what's below (not push it down) the pos: abs or pos: fixed is necessary to layer on top.

I've been going at this for some hours now, trying to figure out a way to circumvent this problem but I can't find a way. Any ideas?

[**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/eTIQiSu/1)

Answer (score 0):

try providing the height of the dropdown using befor the `slideToggle` function

```
$('.navheader #dropdown').height( $(document).height()-400 );
```

since I have no idea of the doc height it is streching a bit too far below. See if you can take care of that :) or let me know ill start editing then.